# JS. Событие при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Какое событие при обновлении страницы? При обновлении страницы, мне нужно чтобы она открывала другую страницу

Comment: никакого - нельзя определить просто открыли страницу или перезагрузили

Comment: Попробуй описать подробнее что именно у тебя сейчас и что и зачем ты хочешь сделать

Comment: Три раза прочитал вопрос, ничего не понял ))))

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать несколько вариантов:

1. С использованием window perfomance

```js
if (window.performance) {
  console.log("Perfomance not supported");
}
if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
console.log( "Страница перезагружена" );
} else {
console.log( "Страница не перезагружена");
}
```

Данное решение подойдет только для мажорных браузеров поддерживающих HTML5 Navigation history

2. Использовать sessionStorage
   Проверяем sessionStorage на наличие флага is_reloaded

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem("is_reloaded")) {
 console.log('Страница перезагружена')
}
```

Также добавляем флаг, при загрузке страницы, что первая загрузка прошла

```js
sessionStorage.setItem("is_reloaded", true);
```

SessionStorage будет работать только пока открытки вкладки, после закрытия данные будут сброшены, по аналогии можно посчитать и кол-во перезагрузок страницы.

Comment: Пункт 1 - ошибка в условии `if (window.performance)`, должно быть логическое отрицание; Инфа о поддержке устарела уже года 3 назад - сейчас большинство браузеров "мажорные".

Comment: я не согласен с вами, вы видимо из Default City и не поддерживали больше World Wide проекты, взгляните на аудиторию азии и страны африки, на их интернет, основной парк устройств и версии браузеров.

Comment: С чем именно Вы не согласны - с ошибкой в примере кода, или с фактическими данными о поддержке данного апи браузерами? Если со вторым, то ознакомьтесь: https://caniuse.com/#feat=nav-timing `p.s.:` Вместо того чтобы тратить слова на фантазии о моей персоне, уделите больше внимания сути и контексту вопроса.

Comment: Со второй частью вашего сообщения. Думаю как раз вам следует с вашей же ссылкой внимательно ознакомиться, а потом уже говорить. IE10 жив, как и Safari версии 10 9 в которых этой поддержки нет. В место занудства, подтяните матчасть.